# how much memory is allocated to jvm process

Tags: java

total memory allocated to the jvm process is equal to the total heap, stack, native heap. i know there are commands for setting the minimum and maximum size limits on the heap.

how about the total memory allocated to the jvm process, is there a limit on that or would it keep on increasing as the number of threads getting created increases.

if there is no limit on the number of threads and since a new stack is created when a new thread is created, would this cause the jvm to keep on increasing its size till there is no more memory left in the RAM?

Answer (score 0):

The total heap.  New threads use heap memory.  You'll OOME if you have too many of them.  Try it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I know it's so. Thread stack is allocated in JVM stack and OS specific.

You can use -Xss to control the default stack size but not its upper limit.

Interesting articles

http://www.onkarjoshi.com/blog/209/using-xss-to-adjust-java-default-thread-stack-size-to-save-memory-and-prevent-stackoverflowerror/

http://blog.codecentric.de/en/2010/01/the-java-memory-architecture-1-act/

http://book.javanb.com/java-threads-3rd/jthreads3-CHP-13-SECT-6.html